# Will [a-z] ever match accented characters in PREG/PCRE?

Tags: php, regex, ascii, pcre

I'm already aware that `\w` in PCRE (particularly PHP's implementation) can sometimes match some non-ASCII characters depending on the locale of the system, but what about `[a-z]`?

I wouldn't think so, but I noticed these lines in one of Drupal's core files (includes/theme.inc, simplified):

```
// To avoid illegal characters in the class,
// we're removing everything disallowed. We are not using 'a-z' as that might leave
// in certain international characters (e.g. German umlauts).
$body_classes[] = preg_replace('![^abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0-9-_]+!s', '', $class);
```

Is this true, or did someone simply get `[a-z]` confused with `\w`?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Long story short: Maybe, depends on the system the app is deployed to, depends how PHP was compiled, welcome to the CF of localization and internationalization.

<s>The underlying PCRE engine takes locale into account when determining what "a-z" means. In a Spanish based locale, ñ would be caught by a-z).  The semantic meaning of a-z is "all the letters between a and z, and ñ is a separate letter in Spanish.</s>

<s>However, the way PHP blindly handles strings as collections of bytes rather than a collection of UTF code points means you have a situation where a-z MIGHT match an accented character</s>.  Given the variety of different systems Drupal gets deployed to, it makes sense that they would choose to be explicit about the allowed characters rather than just trust a-z to do the right thing.

<s>I'd also conjecture that the existence of this regular expression is the result of a bug report being filed about German umlauts not being filtered.</s>

**Update in 2014**: Per [JimmiTh's answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22892863/4668), it looks  like (despite some "confusing-to-non-pcre-core-developers" documentation) that `[a-z]` will only match the characters `abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz` a proverbial 99% of the time.   That said — framework developers tend to get twitchy about vagueness in their code, especially when the code relies on systems (locale specific strings) that PHP doesn't handle as gracefully as you'd like, and servers the developers have no control over.  While the anonymous Drupal developer's comments are incorrect — it wasn't a matter of "getting `[a-z]` confused with `\w`", but instead a Drupal developer being unclear/unsure of how PCRE handled `[a-z]`, and choosing the more specific form of `abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz` to ensure the specific behavior they wanted.

Comment: Was this really true in 2009?

Comment: @WalterTross Still as true today as it was back then.  It's never about what's was/is common, it's about what MIGHT happen with some weird configuration, and making sure your code's robust enough to handle it.

Comment: @AlanStorm, can you provide such a weird configuration? I'm pretty sure there is none!

Answer (score 10):

The **comment** in Drupal's code is **WRONG**.

It's **NOT** true that "`international characters (e.g. German umlauts)`" might match `[a-z]`.

If, e.g., you have the German locale available, you can check it like this:

```php
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'de_DE'); // German locale (not needed, but you never know...)
echo preg_match('/^[a-z]+$/', 'abc') ? "yes\n" : "no\n";
echo preg_match('/^[a-z]+$/', "\xE4bc") ? "yes\n" : "no\n"; // äbc in ISO-8859-1
echo preg_match('/^[a-z]+$/',  "\xC3\xA4bc") ? "yes\n" : "no\n"; // äbc in UTF-8
echo preg_match('/^[a-z]+$/u', "\xC3\xA4bc") ? "yes\n" : "no\n"; // w/ PCRE_UTF8
```

Output (will not change if you replace `de_DE` with `de_DE.UTF-8`):

```
yes
no
no
no
```

The character class `[abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz]` is identical to `[a-z]` in both encodings the PCRE understands: ASCII-derived monobyte and UTF-8 (which is ASCII-derived too). In both of these encodings `[a-z]` is the same as `[\x61-\x7A]`.

Things may have been different when the question was asked in 2009, but in 2014 there is no "weird configuration" that can make PHP's PCRE regex engine interpret `[a-z]` as a class of more than 26 characters (as long as `[a-z]` itself is written as 5 bytes in an ASCII-derived encoding, of course).

Comment: What happens when the PHP file has its encoding changed?

Comment: @AlanStorm: as long as the encoding is ISO-8859-*, UTF-8, or any Windows codepage that contains the English lowercase alphabet: nothing. On the other hand, it looks like PHP can be compiled in order to read, e.g., UTF-16 source code (I didn't know that). I don't have the energy to try it out. If someone has, they can post their findings here.

Answer (score 7):

Just an addition to both the already excellent, if contradicting, answers.

The documentation for the PCRE library has always stated that "Ranges operate in the collating sequence of character values". Which is somewhat vague, and yet very precise.

It refers to collating by the *index* of characters in PCRE's internal character tables, which can be set up to match the current locale using [`pcre_maketables`](http://vcs.pcre.org/viewvc/code/trunk/pcre_maketables.c?view=markup). That function builds the tables in order of char value (`tolower(i)`/`toupper(i)`)

In other words, it doesn't collate by actual cultural sort order (the locale collation info). As an example, while German treats ö the same as o in dictionary collation, ö has a value that makes it appear outside the a-z range in all the common character encodings used for German (ISO-8859-x, unicode encodings etc.) In this case, PCRE would base its determination of whether ö is in the range `[a-z]` on that code value, rather than any actual locale-defined sort order.

PHP has mostly copied [PCRE's documentation](http://www.pcre.org/pcre.txt) verbatim in [their docs](https://php.net/manual/de/regexp.reference.character-classes.php). However, they've actually gone to pains changing the above statement to "Ranges operate in ASCII collating sequence". That statement has been in the docs at least since 2004.

In spite of the above, I'm not quite sure it's true, however.

Well, not in all cases, at least.

The one call PHP makes to `pcre_maketables`... From the [PHP source](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/pcre/php_pcre.c):

```
#if HAVE_SETLOCALE
    if (strcmp(locale, "C"))
        tables = pcre_maketables();
#endif
```

In other words, if the environment for which PHP is compiled has `setlocale` *and* the (LC_CTYPE) locale isn't the POSIX/C locale, the runtime environment's POSIX/C locale's character order is used. Otherwise, the default PCRE tables are used - which are generated (by `pcre_maketables`) when PCRE is compiled - *based on the compiler's locale*:

> This function builds a set of character tables for character values less than 256. These can be passed to pcre_compile() to override PCRE's internal, built-in tables (which were made by pcre_maketables() when PCRE was compiled). You might want to do this if you are using a non-standard locale. The function yields a pointer to the tables.

While German wouldn't be different for `[a-z]` in any common character encoding, if we were dealing with EBCDIC, for example, `[a-z]` would include ± and ~. Granted, EBCDIC is the one character encoding I can think of that doesn't place a-z and A-Z in uninterrupted sequence.

Unless PCRE does some magic when using EBCDIC (and it might), while it's highly unlikely you'd be including umlauts in anything but the most obscure PHP build or runtime environment (using your very own, very special, custom-made locale definition), you *might*, in the case of EBCDIC, include other unintended characters. And for other ranges, "collated in ASCII sequence" doesn't seem entirely accurate.

**ETA:** I could have saved some research by looking for Philip Hazel's own reply to a similar concern:

> > > *Another issue is with character classes ranges. You would think that [a-k] and [x-z] are well defined for latin scripts but that's not the case.*
>
> They are certainly well defined, being equivalent to [\x61-\x6b] and [\x78-\x7a], that is, related to code order, not cultural sorting order.

Comment: [pcre_maketables()](http://vcs.pcre.org/viewvc/code/trunk/pcre_maketables.c?view=markup) only builds the following tables: lower casing table, case-flipping table, character class tables, character type table. It doesn't deal with collations. Regarding EBCDIC, if someone shows me an EBCDIC machine that actually runs PHP, where the PCRE within PHP interprets `[a-z]` as `[\x81-\xA9]`, I surrender.

Comment: Yes. Hence "In other words, it doesn't collate by actual cultural sort order (the locale collation info)". The entire point of the answer *is* that it doesn't deal with collations.

Comment: The bitchy thing with strcmp(3) is that it returns the equivalent of false, when the strings match. So, pcre_maketables is called for anything, BUT the C locale.

Comment: Thanks, fixed. :-) In spite of not doing much C in the past 15 years, I did seem to recall that, looked it up just to be sure, then managed to still write out the explanation wrong. Thankfully, it changes nothing, since that part is simply what was already assumed - that PHP does change the locale of PCRE in some cases when compiling expressions. Which doesn't matter, because there are few, if any, locale encodings that change the code values of a-z.

Comment: @WalterTross, you're right, they would run COBOL, which is like the PHP of the 60ies.