# How do I match accented characters in preg_match()?

Tags: php, regex, special-characters

I've read [how accented characters might sometimes match [a-z]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1930487/will-a-z-ever-match-accented-characters-in-preg-pcre).  What I'd like to know is how I could match a specific accented character. Obviously, `preg_match('/[ñ]/', 'ñ')` does not work.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use the /u modifier. That will enable Unicode for the regexes.
http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php

Comment: Thanks!  This works on my Ubuntu workstation but, unfortunately, it doesn't work on my teammate's Windows XP workstation.

Comment: This might be a PHP incompatibility with Windows, not sure.

Comment: Hmm. Finally got it to work. Had to simplify the expression to use the shorthand `\w` but with the `/u` modifier:  `preg_match('/[\w]/iu', 'ñ');` works!

Answer (score 4):

You can take their codes and match them like \xD0 - heximal sequences if accented symbols are not accepted