# preg_match isn't matching accented characters

Tags: php, regex

Here is a simple test program:

```
<?php
$n = "Baden-Württemberg";
preg_match ("/(.*)([^[:print:]])(.*)/", $n, $m);
print_r ($m);
?>
```

I expected this to NOT match `[^[:print:]]` but the output is this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Baden-Württemberg
    [1] => Baden-W�
    [2] => �
    [3] => rttemberg
)
```

I also tried `/(.*)([^\p{L}\p{M}*\s'-\.])(.*)/` and `/(.*)([^[:print:]])(.*)/u` but get the same result except that `/u` gives `$m[2]='ü'` instead of `�`

How do I match accented characters? [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2250567/how-do-i-match-accented-characters-in-preg-match) hasn't worked in my case.

Comment: You should name your variables more appropriately. If you start cooking an alphabet soup, you're bound to have a bad time later on. `$string` and `$matches` work just as well.

Comment: What OS are you running? Ubuntu with 5.3.15 / `LC_CTYPE=UTF-8` seems to match correctly.

Comment: Ummm... so what **do** you want to match instead? Also your last example with `/u` at the end works fine for me on Windows 7 with PHP 5.3.8. Without `/u` it's like you said later... the first question mark is gone, and the second becomes an `ü`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what are you trying to achieve here.

```
preg_match('/[[:^print:]]/u', '$n, $m);
```

accurately matches the accented character (you can use `[[:^print:]]` as well as `[^[:print:]]` which produces the same result here).

If you use `(.*)` in your pattern it's usually useful to use `U` modifier (ungreedy). In your first example this would give the following result:

```
$n = "Baden-Württemberg";
preg_match ("/(.*)([^[:print:]])(.*)/uU", $n, $m);
print_r ($m);

Array 
( 
[0] => Baden-Wü 
[1] => Baden-W 
[2] => ü 
[3] => 
)
```