# How to validiate for a solely alphabetic string with spaces in PHP?

Tags: php, regex

I know that there is the function `ctype_alpha`, though this one will return `FALSE` when the string contains spaces (white space character).

How do I allow alpha characters and spaces, but nothing else?

Comment: Replace spaces with a number before checking?

Comment: @DanRedux that only works if the string doesn't contain numbers beforehand.

Comment: Why? If it contains numbers beforehand, it'll return false correctly. If it contains numbers after, it'll return false correctly.. The only thing it will do is treat spaces as bad tokens by turning them into bad tokens.

Comment: @DanRedux you misread the question. The OP wants to _accept_ strings that contain spaces; the problem with `ctype_alpha` is that it does not.

Comment: Ohhh. Then change spaces to the letter 'a'? :P

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$is_alpha_space = ctype_alpha(str_replace(' ', '', $input)));
```

or

```
$is_alpha_space = preg_match('/^[a-z\s]*$/i', $input);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I like the first one. I am just wondering for learning purposes, how do you know about that first one? Because I cannot even tell by the documentation.

Comment: It's not one function. It uses `str_replace()` to remove spaces and then `ctype_alpha()` to check that the result of that is alphabetical.

Comment: I do understand, though how do you know about it, when the ctype page in the documentation does not point it out (that you can do that), or does it? I can not tell.

Comment: @Carpet you have to think about what you want to accomplish and sometimes you have to accomplish it in steps. You ask yourself, "If `ctype_alpha` doesn't allow spaces, what can I do about that?" The answer is that you can remove the spaces before you pass it to `ctype_alpha` so you go looking for something that will do that. If you look at the **Return Values** section of the manual entry for `str_replace`, you see that it returns a string with the replaced values. So you can pass the return value of `str_replace` to `ctype_alpha`.

Comment: It's worthwhile to browse the PHP manual. The function names are often self-explanatory. There is a list of all the functions for that section in the sidebar of each page and there is a list of related functions in the **See Also** section. Plus, most pages have user-contributed code and help.

Comment: Note that this regular expression will allow an empty string and a string with just spaces. That may or may not be the desired result.

Comment: I can't make single character edits but you have one too many ) in the first example.

Answer (score 2):

```
if (preg_match("^/[a-zA-Z ]+$/", $input)) {
    // input matches
}
```

Demo: http://ideone.com/jp6Wi
Docs: http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php

Comment: Though be aware that `[a-z]` can [match different characters depending on the system's locale settings](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1930487/will-a-z-ever-match-accented-characters-in-preg-pcre).

Comment: There is a typo in the regex. It should start with `/^` rather than `^/`.

Comment: Note that this regular expression will allow a string with just spaces. That may or may not be the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

`ctype_alpha(preg_replace('/\s/', '', $mystring))`

The inner expression returns the string without spaces, and then you use ctype_alpha`` as you wish

Comment: This falls under the category of **If you don't need fancy replacing rules, you should always use `str_replace` instead of `preg_replace`.**

Answer (score 0):

Removing the spaces is the way to go, but remember ctype_alpha results in a false on an empty string these days! Below the method I use...

```
function validateAlpha($valueToValidate, $spaceAllowed = false) {
    if ($spaceAllowed) {
        $valueToValidate = str_replace(' ', '', $valueToValidate);
    }
    if (strlen($valueToValidate) == 0) {
        return true;
    }
    return ctype_alpha($valueToValidate);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would work around with a Simple regex and with the php function [preg_match()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) like this:

```
if(preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]+$/", $varToCheck)){
  //your code here
}
```

The important part here is the regex that identifies the parts you want, in my case I wanted text for a name field and with spaces like the case in here.[a-z] is the range from a to z, A-Z are the range from A to Z and the " " at the end represents the spaces.

Hope this helps someone.