# Unexpected behavior by [NSRegularExpression stringByReplacingMatchesInString]

Tags: objective-c, regex, cocoa, nsregularexpression

I was tinkering with Objective-C today, but I'm running into some odd behavior. Basically I was trying to replace all non-alphabetic lowercase characters from an NSString. What I had basically boiled down to:

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

  @autoreleasepool {
    NSError *error;
    NSRegularExpression *pattern = [[NSRegularExpression alloc] initWithPattern:@"/[^abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz]/" options:0 error:&error];
    NSString *replacableStuff = @"a b c\nd e";
    NSLog(@"%@", [pattern stringByReplacingMatchesInString:replacableStuff options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [replacableStuff length]) withTemplate:@""]);

  }
    return 0;
}
```

However, the replacement never seems to happen; running this logs "a b c\nd e" to the log thingie. (I was expecting to see "abcde".) I tried simpler patterns like `/[aeiou]/` or even just `/a/`, but no matter what I try, the stringByReplacingMatchesInString method doesn't seem to actually be replacing anything. What am I overlooking?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to remove slashes on both sides of your pattern. Slashes are not metacharacters in cocoa's regular expressions, so the strings matched by your current expression would be single letters with slashes on both sides - `/a/`, `/b/`, `/c/`, and so on.

You can also use a *range* in your character class, like this:

```
NSRegularExpression *pattern = [[NSRegularExpression alloc] initWithPattern:@"[^a-z]" options:0 error:&error];
```

Comment: Aha! That was it. Of course, now I feel like a doofus for not noticing that earlier in all the examples I looked at. Thanks! As for the range thing, I learned - [here on this site](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1930487/will-a-z-ever-match-accented-characters-in-preg-pcre), actually - that letter ranges can match different letters depending on system locale when it comes to PHP's PCRE library, so I've gotten in the habit of writing them out when there may be ambiguity. Is this something I don't need to worry about with NSRegularExpression?

Comment: @GarrettAlbright It's a good point about the ranges being dependent on the encoding. However, in the environments on which Objective C programs run (macs and ios devices) you have zero chance of hitting an unorthodox encoding where the letters of latin alphabet are not arranged in a contiguous block.